# Testflight is crashing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

TestFlight is crashing before my app has a chance to run.

I have an iOS app I'm planning to distribute to external testers.  The build has been approved for TestFlight testing.  I invited myself (under a different apple ID than the one I use for development) to be the first tester.  In TestFlight, I hit "redeem" and type the invitation code I was sent.  For a brief fraction of a second I see a screen popup that says "redeeming app", then TestFlight kicks me out to my home screen.  I've found that it doesn't matter what I input for the invitation code -- it's probably crashing before it even has a chance to communicate with the Apple servers.

Has any one else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The email address I signed up for external testing didn't match the apple ID.  I re-issued the invitation with the email matching the ID, and now it works.